# String was not declared?

Tags: c++

```
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
namespace charcount 
{
    int ShowPerCent();
    int PerCent();
    int Values(char letter);
    int analize(string var);
}
```

This code is all part of "functions.h" of my project. This says:

```
functions.h: 7:13: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
```

And I don't understand why says that this. I try with `std::string` and nope. Anyone know what happens? If you need more additional information ask.

Comment: We're not really fond of expletives here, in general.

Answer (score 5):

The correct header is `<string>`. Change the include directive to:

```
#include <string>
```

The C++ standard library headers *do not* end with `.h`.

It's considered very bad practice to do `using namespace std;`, especially in a header file. This pollutes the global namespace with names from the `std` namespace and propagates said pollution to any file that includes it.

Answer (score 2):

In C,

```
#include <string.h>
```

gives you the C string header (`strlen()`, `strcmp()` et al.).

In C++,

```
#include <string.h>
```

is deprecated, but gives you the same C string header. You are encouraged to use

```
#include <cstring>
```

instead, which gives you the same functions but in the `std::` namespace (where they belong).

If you want `std::string`, the object-oriented auto-allocating auto-expanding C++ niceness, you would have to:

```
#include <string>
```

And please, don't use `using namespace`, *especially* not in combination with `std::`. The idea is to be *explicit* about which namespace a given identifier comes from.

**Edit:** Seconding sftrabbit, who typed quicker than me. While `using namespace` might be pardonable in your .cpp files, in headers it's a capital offense, because including your header could make perfectly valid C++ code invalid all of a sudden, because you changed the namespace.

Comment: `#include <cstring>

namespace charcount {
int ShowPerCent();
int PerCent();
int Values(char letter);
int analize(std::string var);
}`  It says the same....